# Laravel does not redirect to login page when I try to access to home page

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, web, laravel-middleware

I try writting the url http://127.0.0.1:8000/home and I'm not logged in and it shows me home page but obviously not loaded correctly, What I want is when I write http://127.0.0.1:8000/home to redirect me to http://127.0.0.1:8000/login page I know this works in fresh projects with make:auth module, I don't know why stopped workin.

In my home I have this

```
 public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }
```

and my routes file:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('auth\login');
});

Auth::routes();


Route::post('create','IngresarSolicitud@store');
Route::get('/home','IngresarSolicitud@informacionempleado');
```

Comment: Welcome. Did you check your log file in `storage/logs`? What have you changed? Why do you have two routes pointing to `/home`?

Comment: With that auth middleware in your controller it should just work fine. This could be an issue with the browser you are using, caching stuff. Clear cache and on the browser try using a private window (incognito)

Answer (score 1):

I added ->middleware('auth'); at the end of my routes to redirect to login in this case, thanks